# How to predict the time of occurrence of specific event on daily basis using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I am collecting the activities of a person in a day with time stamp data .Assume I am tracking 4 different activities that person is doing and an event occurring time in that day.event can occur multiple times also in a day. I am trying to predict the event occurring time in a day using the historical data to train a model.

My model should give an out put as a time  having the maximum probability of that event to happen.

please suggest what should be the machine learning approach to this problem.

Thanks in advance for the help on this.

Answer (score -3):

If you have a background in machine learning/statistics then You going to achieve your project within minimal time.

Here is a glimpse for you.

Machine learning has various algorithms to implement, depending on the kind of the problem you're solving.so,in this case your problem can be solved by predictive analysis model which is based on predicting time driven events effectively.And under the hood,you'd apply nor use regression algorithm.(linear/logistic)

It uses historical data to predict future events and still the historical data can be used to generate mathematical model which you can as well use to capture important events or trends.Then for predictive model,you can use it on current data to predict what time an event will happen.

For your information,there are software packages/libraries which can as well help you to implement the above algorithm effectively.

Hope this helps.